# nodejs request.post be unable to get the cookies , but request.get is can 。

Tags: node.js, post, cookies, request

When i use  code  login the site after  . I want send a post request , and server is unable to get the cookies ,but get request is ok.

my code :

```
var req = require('request');
req.defaults({ jar: true });

 const loginUrl = 'https://www.a.com/auth/login';
 const scoreUrl = 'https://app-test.a.com/bms/CustomerAccount/member/get-list-task?_ac=OperationCenter&_smp=OperationCenter.Member';

function login(options, cb) {

req.post({
    url: loginUrl,
    form: {
        'tenantCode': 'jfdc',
        'userName': 'jfdc',
        'password': 'sh123456'
    }
},
    function (err, res, body) {
        var cb = function (err, res, body) {
            console.log(body);
        };

        options = {
            url: scoreUrl,
            data: {
                page: 1,
                pageSize: 10,
                corp_id: '11b11db4-e907-4f1f-8835-b9daab6e1f23',
                key: '111111111111111',
                sort_list: [],
                _t: 1534647594968
            }
        };
        req.post(options, cb);
    });
}

login();
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find cookie in:

```
res.headers['set-cookie']
```

and use it for next request.

Comment: yes , I can get the cookie  。 but  check cookie  in  request.header at  'app-test.a.com' .